# Does Vue support reactivity on Map and Set data types?

Tags: vue.js

The docs for Vue.js mention the smart auto-change-tracking for *plain Javascript objects*:

> When you pass a plain JavaScript object to a Vue instance as its data option, Vue.js will walk through all of its properties and convert them to getter/setters using Object.defineProperty.

Since Javascript's `Map` and `Set` datatypes are designed to be used with their in-built `get`/`set` methods, how can I get Vue to track calls (and therefore, changes) to the internal state of `Map`s and `Set`s?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### Vue 3

Yes, it does.

Vue 3 docs cover these at [Reactivity in depth](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html) and [Basic Reactivity APIs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html).

There are four kinds of "reactive" and the "reference" in addition. I'm still trying to find the usage patterns that suit me, after 6+ months with Vue 3 and ES6 coding. The main question is, whether to use `Reactive` or `Reference`.

#### Reference

`Reference` is the easy way to go. This is what gets returned by `computed`, for example. It makes a reactive version of one's JavaScript value, e.g. a `Map` or a `Set`.

There's a gotcha. If one uses `Reference` in one's JavaScript, a `.value` needs to be added to dereference the value. Using it in template HTML does not need that addition. This makes `Reference` perfect for UI facing things, but less so for internal programming.

I currently add `Ref` postfix to the name of any value or function that provides a `Reference`. That's just me. It's easy to get confused if one uses both `Reference` and `Reactive` (TypeScript would help, here).

#### Reactive

`Reactive` is made for Map-like use. One can initialise it as:

```
const rve = reactive( new Map() )
```

Accessing such does not need the `.value`. However, it seems `Reactive` does not have the enumeration methods (e.g. `.entries()`) that would allow it to be used Map-like. Therefore, it seems aimed at a use case where you know the keys of an object. But this may change.

I wish `Reactive` was brought in the direction that it can be used as a 1:1 replacement for ES `Map`. This would make it easy for me: `Reactive` for `Map`s and `Reference` for the rest.

I would also wish the name would change, to bring them closer. `RMap` would be fine - maybe I'll make one (derive from `Reactive` and add the enumeration methods).

#### Summary

The strong answer, with Vue 3, is "YES".

However, the developer guidance can be made more straightforward, clearly stating which would be the logic for picking `Reference` or `Reactive`, and what eg. their runtime pros and cons are, without needing to read various blog posts.

---

Edit: My current leaning is towards `Ref`, but I try to unwrap the reactivity quite early within the code, leading to just one `.value` within a `computed`.

Comment: For everyone with a less-green stack: not supported without workarounds in Vue 2

Comment: I do not find referencens to `Map` and `Set` in mentioned articles. This answer also only explains the general workings of `ref` and `reactive` nothing `Map` or `Set` specific. Most importantly, it does not answer the question whether `myMapRef.value.set(..., ...)` would trigger reactivity. Downvote

Answer (score 78):

Vue.js does not support reactivity on `Map` and `Set` data types (yet?).

The [feature ticket](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2410#issuecomment-318487855) has some discussion and this work around (by user "inca"):

> Sets and Maps are not observable by Vue. In order to use those —
>   either in `v-for`, or in computed properties, methods, watchers,
>   template expressions, etc. — you need to create a serializable replica
>   of this structure and expose it to Vue. Here's a naive example which
>   uses a simple counter for providing Vue with information that `Set` is
>   updated:
>
> ```
> data() {
>   mySetChangeTracker: 1,
>   mySet: new Set(),
> },
>
> computed: {
>   mySetAsList() { 
>     // By using `mySetChangeTracker` we tell Vue that this property depends on it,
>     // so it gets re-evaluated whenever `mySetChangeTracker` changes
>     return this.mySetChangeTracker && Array.from(this.mySet);
>   },
> },
>
> methods: {
>   add(item) {
>     this.mySet.add(item);
>     // Trigger Vue updates
>     this.mySetChangeTracker += 1;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> This illustrates a kinda hacky but 100% working method for making
>   non-observable data reactive. Still, in real world cases I ended up
>   with serialized versions of Sets/Maps (e.g. you'd probably want to
>   store the modified versions of sets/maps in localstorage and thus
>   serialize them anyway), so no artificial counters/hacks were involved.

Comment: This is no longer the case if you're on Vue 3 (now the new default version). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64512468/885922

Answer (score 22):

As far as I know, Vue's reactivity tracks assignments. If you perform an assignment on your set, it should track reactivity, for example:

```
methods: {
  add(item) {
    this.mySet = new Set(this.mySet.add(item));
  }
}
```

This gives you a cleaner code, but with an obvious problem: performance.

Just pick your solution according to your needs :)

Comment: Very nice inside, thanks :) I have refactored my code to Array for now. But I wander: If I need to delete elem, what is more performant. Setting `new Set()`, or making a `.filter()` on array ?

Comment: Maybe there is a way to manually trigger reactivity without creating a copy of the set? Like maybe `const tmp = this.mySet; this.mySet = null; this.mySet = tmp.add(item);`

Answer (score 0):

Using [@vue/composition-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/composition-api) I have come up with the following solution for Vue 2.

```
// useReactiveSet.ts
import { ref, computed } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default function useReactiveSet<T>() {
  const version = ref(1)
  class ReactiveSet extends Set<T> {
    add(value: T) {
      super.add(value)
      version.value += 1
      return this
    }
  }
  const inner = ref(new ReactiveSet())

  const set = computed(() => {
    version.value
    return inner.value
  })

  return set
}
```

```
// Component.vue
{
  // ...
  setup() {
    const set = useReactiveSet<number>()

    setTimeout(() => {
      // this will trigger rerender
      set.value.add(2)
    }, 1000)

    return {
      set,
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

You can use the same approach for `Map`.

There is package [vue-reactive-collection](https://github.com/bluecanvas/vue-reactive-collection) which adds support for reactive `Map` and `Set` in Vue 2.

Comment: Any plans to update this to support Vue 2.7?