# Adding view-only properties to a tree data object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a tree component where nodes can be moved around. The component and data structure are similar to the one used in the [Tree View example in the Vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/tree-view.html).

The data structure looks like this (irrelevant properties removed):

```
[
  {"id": 1, "children": []},
  {"id": 2, "children": []},
  {"id": 3, "children": [
    {"id": 4, "children": [
      {"id": 5, "children": []},
      {"id": 6, "children": []}
    ]}
  ]}
]
```

The nodes represent "folders" that can be folded or expanded in the view. The `FolderNode` component looks like this:

```
export default {
  name: 'FolderNode',
  props: {
    node: { type: Object, required: true },
  },
  data: () => ({
    expanded: true,
  }),

  methods: {
    toggleExpand() {
      this.expanded = !this.expanded;
    },
  },
};
```

The template is:

```
<template>
  <li>
    <span class="node-icon">
      <span @click="toggleExpand">[{{ expanded ? '-' : '+' }}]</span>
    </span>
    <span class="node-label">{{ node.id }}</span>
    <ol
      v-if="node.children && node.children.length"
      v-show="expanded"
    >
      <FolderNode
        v-for="child in node.children"
        :key="child.id"
        :node="child"
      />
    </ol>
  </li>
</template>
```

This part works fine. I added drag and drop functionality to move nodes around (not shown above for simplicity) in the tree. When nodes are removed and inserted elsewhere, Vue.js instantiates new `FolderNode` components  automatically to reflect the changes. These new `FolderNode` instances are created (when a node is moved to a different parent) with the default `expanded` state to `true`. I was hoping the `:key` property would work across different parents, but it only reuses components (and keeps their `expanded` state) for children of the same parent `FolderNode`.

**So, how can I keep the folders' `expanded` state (and other display state) when they are moved?**

The tree object will be used by other parts of the application so I can't add an `expanded` property directly to its nodes which would be the easiest solution. Besides, `expanded` is strictly "display state" and has nothing to do with the tree data.

I've thought of 2 possible solutions which I don't find really appealing:

1. Create a parallel tree structure mirroring the data tree that holds the display state. Pass this to the folder components and have them query that to know their state.
2. Use a map to map nodes of the data tree to a state object. The problem is that [maps are not reactive in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130105/does-vue-support-reactivity-on-map-and-set-data-types) so I'd have to resort to ugly hacks to make it work.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I take it `node.id` is a `:key`? It doesn't change while moving node?

Comment: @Styx That's right `:key="child.id"` refers to a `node.id` property

Comment: @Styx and it doesn't change when moving nodes. The node objects themselves are also kept when they are moved. That is I'm not creating new objects when nodes are moved.

Comment: This contradicts with what you said in question: _New FolderNode instances are created when a node is moved to a different parent with the default expanded state to true._

Comment: Ah, I see, your `expanded` is not stored in `node` object. Why, though?

Comment: I tried to clarify the question regarding the instantiation part. I meant that Vue.js takes care of that through its regular mechanism. The `FolderNode` is the component and the "node" is the data object. The tree will be displayed (and possibly modified) in other ways by other components so `expanded` should not be part of it since it's strictly relevant to the display state. For example, I can have 2 `FolderNode` hierarchies where one is showing only part of the tree, etc.

Comment: Ahha, so `expanded` state of the same node depends on its root tree, right?

Comment: @Styx Exactly! (padding)

Comment: Just one more question to clarify: is the root component is the same `FolderNode` or some another like `FolderTree`?

Comment: It's a different component that loops through the root tree nodes and creates `FolderNode`s for them. I guess it could be a `FolderNode` eventually if I need a "root" folder for display purposes. If is has any bearing on a solution, I can go either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility is to go with option 2 without using a map. In fact the map, while semantically correct, turns out to not be needed at all!

The "root" component creates a "tree view state" object that holds the state of `expanded` of each node. Something like:

```
const treeViewState = {};
// Visit each node and create its initial view state object to make it reactive
walkNodes(tree, (node, level) => {
  treeViewState[node.id] = {
    expanded: level < 1, // Simple logic to only expand the first level by default
  };
});
```

The "root" component then `provide`s the `treeViewState` to its children components through Vue's injection mechanism.

Each `FolderNode` then accesses its display state through its node's unique id. This is used to index the `treeViewState` object.

Comment: This looks promising. While I don't see a problem with Vue `provide/inject` mechanism, I prefer that it be used only for injecting functions or constants rather than actual data. But it is just my historical context that forces me to have this prejudice. Also, if the tree changes, do you plan to drop all the keys from `treeViewState` object? Due to Vue provide/inject, you cannot create a new object. Maybe consider injecting ES Proxy instead of an actual `treeViewState` object.

Comment: @HarshalPatil Regarding the reactivity, I think it can work if I inject an accessor function instead of the `treeViewState` object directly. This is what @chekmare did in his demo. Regarding dropped nodes, I have two options: 1. ignore it and take the (small) memory leak hit. 2. Remove the state of a node when it is removed from the tree.

Answer (score 1):

We faced a similar problem when we build a tree component. We had the exact same thought.

Initially, we created a parallel data structure and with the help of `Ramda`, we would merge the internal data model external tree structure. But this proved not very elegant. And, tree conciliation is very difficult to achieve.

But, if you take another perspective on this approach, then it makes sense to make `expanded` as part of the **tree Node object**. There are multiple use cases for this:

- Sometimes you might want to show the first Node as expanded
- During the search operation, all the Nodes with specific name must expand the way it happens in most of the code editors.
- When used as a file explorer, nodes containing specific files must be expanded by default.

And there are many other cases where it proves useful. We are using TypeScript, we simply declare that property as optional like:

```
export interface TreeNode<T extends any> {
    label: string;
    expanded: boolean;
    children: Array<TreeNode<T>>;

    isDisabled?: boolean;

    // Holds the state if tree/node selected or not
    select?: boolean;

    // Unique key which identifies each node
    _id?: string;

    // Any other data that needs to be stored
    context?: T;
}
```

As far as API is concerned, they need not be bothered about these additional keys as they are optional. Thus, it becomes trivial to support **drag-n-drop** with expanded state

Comment: Thanks for your insight. You are right about the useful use cases. I'd like to be able to have multiple independent "component trees" that display the same tree though. Each one would have a separate set of `expanded` states per node. Maybe I can live without that however.

Comment: Since you faced a similar situation, would you spare 2 minutes to look at the other solution I just posted? It seems like it solves the separate state per tree issue neatly, but I might have missed something.