# Can i edit vue data by reference?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, reactive-programming

Let me take an example to explain my problem.

Example: I have a person class which looks similar to this

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    celebrateBirthday() {
        console.log("Happy Birthday");
        this.age += 1;
    }
}
```

and I use this class inside vue like this

```
data() {
    return {
        person: new Person("Kireeti", 26)
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.person.celebrateBirthday();
}
```

usually, we would do

```
mounted() {
    this.person.age += 1 
}
```

but I want to do it within the class for obvious reasons. this works for me because objects have references. But I wonder can I do this?

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: You may want to look into [class-based API when declaring components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components).

Comment: Both approaches are working. So obviously you can do it.

Comment: @YomS. It seems like the approach tailor written for typescript devs, do you know any big libraries using this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When manipulating objects from components like here:

```
data() {
    return {
        person: new Person("Kireeti", 26)
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.person.celebrateBirthday();
}
```

This way is in fact **arguably better** than just doing `this.person.age += 1` in the component.

The reason is that, while adding 1 year to `person.age` is really simple, other objects may have more complex conditions. Maybe you modify your code so `celebrateBirthday` has some constraints, or do more modifications on the person's state, apart of the age.

You absolutely don't want to have to handle that logic in a Vue component, since other components may be using `Person` objects as well. Keeping that logic in the class seems the better approach.

#### Possible caveats

The things that can go wrong using objects references all has to do with **reactivity**. If `Person` had an array of `friends`, and if your component you rely on its changes, like:

```
<friend-component v-for="friend in friends" :data="friend" />
```

You need to be careful and modify the inner person `friends` array in a way that [Vue can track](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/). You cannot rely [on Sets or Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130105/does-vue-support-reactivity-on-map-and-set-data-types). there are [some other limitations too](https://medium.com/js-dojo/reactivity-in-vue-js-and-its-pitfalls-de07a29c9407). Also you need to be careful to set `{deep: true}` when watching objects changes.

However, all of this is the same for variables belonging to your Vue component or to an object: basically there's no problem on relying on objects references, as far as I know.

Comment: Do you think this approach is good for nested data? like, say friends on the person object are also person object themselves and they can also celebrateBirthday within the class.

Comment: I really don't know what problems that approach can give to vue reactive getters and setters, if the level of nested elements gets really big and/or there are circular references.  I couldn't find any links pointing problems with that, so I assume it should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's no harm in using it the class way.